# Переключение точек сбыта

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Экспериментирую с созданием сайта-магазина на laravel 5.7. Пытаюсь реализовать функционал точек сбыта - отдельных магазинов, регионов, стран и т.п., которым присущи свои отдельные товары и цены.

Переключатель в хедере. При посещении сайта автоматически устанавливается значение по-умолчанию (потом быть может будет определяться по положению).

Проблема в том, что я не могу решить, как это сделать. Пользователь заходит на сайт и... и что? Где должна описываться логика? Вид (хедер) - общий для всех страниц. Там нужно отобрать выбранный рынок сбыта. А значит, нужно это где-то хранить. И код должен отработать сразу же при открытии сайта. Т.е. это что-то глобальное с доступом к кешу. С помощью чего это лучше всего сделать и как?